# How to check time is between two time only night in android

Tags: java, android, datetime-comparison

in my android app I have the condition if selected time is greater than 11:00 PM and 07:00 AM then there will be extra charges. it applicable only at night. currently, my code is work correctly but when I am selecting a time in day condition is getting true.

**here is my code**

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


                String startDatetime = "11:00 PM";
                String endDatetime = "07:00 AM";
                SimpleDateFormat formatfornightcharges = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm aa");
                int Hr24 = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

                try {
                    Date startDate = formatfornightcharges.parse(startDatetime);
                    Date selectedTimeforBooking = formatfornightcharges.parse(time_for_night);
                    Date endDate = formatfornightcharges.parse(endDatetime);
                        if (selectedTimeforBooking.after(startDate) || selectedTimeforBooking.before(endDate)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            night_extra_charges = 200;
                            tv_text.setText("" + night_extra_charges);
                        } else {
                            night_extra_charges = 0;
                            tv_text.setText("" + night_extra_charges);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,it is working for all time, only change time_for_night in this format :-

```
String startDatetime = "11:00 PM";
        String endDatetime = "07:00 AM";
        String time_for_night = "11:05 PM";
        Integer night_extra_charges=0;
        SimpleDateFormat formatfornightcharges = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Date startDate = formatfornightcharges.parse(startDatetime);
            Date selectedTimeforBooking = formatfornightcharges.parse(time_for_night);
            Date endDate = formatfornightcharges.parse(endDatetime);
            if ((selectedTimeforBooking.after(startDate)) || (selectedTimeforBooking.before(endDate))) {
                Toast.makeText(ScanDocumentsActivity.this, "200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                night_extra_charges = 200;
                Log.wtf("night_extra_charges",""+night_extra_charges);
            } else {
                night_extra_charges = 0;
                Log.wtf("night_extra_charges",""+night_extra_charges);
                Toast.makeText(ScanDocumentsActivity.this, "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to change the formatter to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatfornightcharges = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.US);
```

instead of `"hh:MM aa"`.

Comment: but if i have added && it not true even i am selecting night time

Comment: You must use `&&` because you want the time to be between `startDate` and `endDate`. If you use `||` then all times return `true` because all times are either after `startDate` or before `endDate`. If still you don't get the result you want, you must debug to find the problem. What is the value of `time_for_night` that fails? Is it parsed correctly to `selectedTimeforBooking`?

Comment: Startdate Thu Jan 01 11:00:00 GMT+05:30 1970                  selectedTimeforBooking = Thu Jan 01 11:55:00 GMT+05:30 1970                        
end time=Thu Jan 01 07:00:00 GMT+05:30 1970                                                            in this case condition should true but it goes in else condition

Comment: End time should be  end time=Wed Jan 02 07:00:00 GMT+05:30 1970 NOT end time=Thu Jan 01 07:00:00 GMT+05:30 1970

Comment: See my edited answer. The times were not formatted correctly.

Comment: your answer is working for only today but when i am selecting time on tomorrow morning it will goes in else condition

Comment: startDate=Thu Jan 01 23:00:00 GMT+05:30 1970            selectedTimeforBooking=Thu Jan 01 04:30:00 GMT+05:30 1970            endDate=Fri Jan 02 07:00:00 GMT+05:30 1970

Comment: You store only the time in the date variables. This is why you get all these inconsistencies. Check my edited answer.